# How to set the distance between the axis of QCustomPlot and the original edge of the QWidget to 0?

Tags: qt, qcustomplot

I promoted a QWidget to QCustomPlot and set the number of coordinates not to display. I add 4 QPushButtons and a QCustomplot to a gridlayout like image 1

[image: image 1]

What I want is the yaxis of QCustomPlot to be aligned with the QPushButton like image 2

[image: image 2]

However, there is a distance between the axis and the original edge of the QWidget like image 3

[image: image 3]

How do I set the axis of QCustomPlot to the boundary of the qwidget to 0?

Besides,I want to set the style of xaxis and yaxis like image 4

[image: image 4]

The code of mainwindow.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>399</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QWidget" name="gridWidget" native="true">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>181</width>
      <height>251</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QWidget{border:2px solid rgb(0, 100, 238);}</string>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
     <item row="0" column="1">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true"/>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true"/>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="3">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="2">
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>40</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string/>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0" colspan="4">
      <widget class="QCustomPlot" name="widget" native="true"/>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>399</width>
     <height>17</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>QCustomPlot</class>
   <extends>QWidget</extends>
   <header location="global">qcustomplot.h</header>
   <container>1</container>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Is there any easy way to realize this ? Thanks for any Suggestions!

Comment: provide a [mre] and show a screenshot...

Comment: Sorry I didn't add any codes because I just add 4 buttons and a qcustomplot to a gridlayout. I did all this in the UI designer, not in code. And I have add screenshots into my question.

Comment: share the .ui ....

Comment: I have add the .ui into my question. But in my opinion, I think the way to solve this problem is to change the codes of qcustomplot.cpp. This is just my point of view. There may be other better ways to deal with this.

Comment: If you discover that part of the source code to modify so that it works then you could look for a public method that you can modify from mainwindow.cpp without modifying qcustomplot.